# Laravel 5 - Task schedule withoutOverlapping not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I try to run schedule on Laravel 5. Its work fine when I run this:

```
$schedule->call(function() {
   // do something here..
})->everyMinute();
```

But when I add `withoutOverlapping()`, the scheduler never run the task:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
   // do something here..
})->everyMinute()->name('job_name')->withoutOverlapping();
```

*these schedule code is written at /app/Console/Kernel.php

Comment: I tried, but I got error when starting the server `[LogicException] A scheduled event name is required to prevent overlapping. Use the 'name' method before 'withoutOverlapping'.`

Comment: Can you please accept the better answer?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The order is important, but it was never mentioned.

Try this

```
$schedule->call(function () {
   // do something here..
})->name('job_name')->withoutOverlapping()->everyMinute();
```

This is how it worked for me:

> (1) call -> (2) name -> (3) withoutOverlapping -> (4) dailyAt -> (5) onOneServer

when you mess around with the order you can get errors like

> A scheduled event name is required to prevent overlapping. Use the `name` method before 'withoutOverlapping'.

or

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule::name()

Comment: THIS is the answer! As said, name and order are important (and it's not mention THAT clearly in the documentary). Thanks @Yev :)

Comment: Yes it is a bad design, setter-methods should be separated from the executing methods.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Is this still an issue with Laravel 8 or was this fixed? Can't seem to see any docs on it

Comment: I use laravel 8 and I still follow the order from this answer to avoid problems. If you follow the order you are safe. Not sure if it was fixed.

Comment: @JonathanBird agree. i got bug to in Laravel 8. My alternative is manually using symfony/lock package

Answer (score 17):

Delete `->everyMinute()` when using `->withoutOverlapping()` it will still run every minute but without overlapping.

## UPDATE

Since Laravel v. 5.5+ you can specify on how many minutes must pass before the "without overlapping" lock expires.

eg. `->withoutOverlapping(10)` can be used to unlock the "overlapping" when 10 minutes will pass.

Comment: I already resolve it long time ago but finally I got proper way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: It makes sense! This is because the cron job already calls the script every minute, I just don't understand why this ```->everyMinute()``` would affect it.Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you edited the answer, and it suits the question, but it is still not correct on the basis level. The parameter you set in the `->withoutOverlapping(10)` is not a replacement for setting the schedule. This parameter is not flexible enough, for example `->dailyAt(...)` will not be replaced. Please see my answer to get explanation on how to use both setters in a chain. Cheers.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev I havn't updated the answer to "suit the question" because the original answer already suits the question(as can be seen by being answered and comments). To end the comments nonsense I will just say that you Sir should start reading and understanding, mostly the docs - eg. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling because what I updated is the info about an update to `->withoutOvelapping()` that Laravel did. I never said it is a replacement.

Comment: @Vizjerei, Since you agree that one is not a replacement for the another, and there should be a way for these two setters to coexist, can you please let me know why you down-voted my answer? Because this is what is shown in my answer - a way to combine the setters. P.S. I did not say that you answer was not good before the update.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev 1) you edited you comment 2) "I never said it is a replacement" - what I ment was that it is not a replacment for my answer and it is just an informative note about `withoutOverlapping`. 3) I've downvoted you because youve donwvoted me and saying that my answer is wrong. Plus the answer was given in 2015! Plus plus I have a feeling that you have deleted 2 of my comments :(

Comment: @Vizjerei 1) There is a 5 minutes limit of editing the comment, I could not do it. 2) I don't have a permission to delete other peoples comments. If someone deleted it, then there was a reason. 3) if you still think that ->withoutOverlapping(10) is a relplacement for [Schedule Frequency Options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options), than how would you replace `->dailyAt(`? There is no way to do it, that is why your answer is not correct, no matter what year it was made. That is why I down-voted it. You cannot down-vote my answer because of revenge.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev This is my last comment to this topic. I never said that your answer is incorrect just like you are saying to my answer all the time. You clearly don't understand the meaning my answer is giving. I did down vote you because I had really challenging few days(tldr: pissed and mega tiered) and you where saying that my answer is wrong where it clearly isn't. I can't change my vote so I apologize for that. I understand your approach and I have never said it is wrong but please try to understand my answer as well.

Comment: @Vizjerei, thank you very much for you kind words. I apologise for causing you all this trouble. Please forgive me. P.S  I have changed my answer so now you can change your vote.

Answer (score 4):

withoutOverlapping method creates a mutex file when a command is executed and deletes the mutex file when it execution is finished.

Scheduler check if mutex file is present for any command it doesn't allow to execute it again.

In your case the mutex file is not deleted and it prevents the command to run again.

You can clear the laravel cache to make it work again using php artisan cache:clear

Comment: I had this problem after a task failed due to lack of disk space. After running the "php artisan" command above, everything went fine again.

Answer (score 1):

The cron withoutOverlapping() is now working. Let's understand how it works
For example:

```
$schedule->command('command')
                    ->hourly()
                    ->withoutOverlapping();
```

The withoutOverlapping means when cron runs then it will generate a lock file in storage/framework/ directory and once it's completed then it will delete the lock file. Now next time onwards, it will check weather the lock file is there or not. If lock file is there that means the previous cron is not completed and it will not allow the cron to overlap the previous one.

```
In this scenario, the lock file is there into the storage/framework/ directory so that the cron is not working
```

**Lock file looks like:** schedule-random_string
For example: schedule-0bfdb7f0bc14b27d84c7d6f2a2528e85b0847fc6

**To Fix:** Remove or rename the lock file (storage/framework/schedule-0bfdb7f0bc14b27d84c7d6f2a2528e85b0847fc6)

Comment: Note that it only saves a file if that's what your environment file is set at. It could be in redis etc.