# Laravel Scheduler don't run commands, but they can be run manually

Tags: php, laravel, schedule

I have those 3 commands to run in schedule.

```php
$schedule->command("update:branchsales")->everyFiveMinutes()->timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')->withoutOverlapping();
$schedule->command("update:billing")->everyFiveMinutes()->timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')->withoutOverlapping();
$schedule->command("update:sales")->everyFiveMinutes()->timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')->withoutOverlapping();
```

But in log, we can see only 2 of them are actually running.

```js
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:sales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:branchsales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:sales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:branchsales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

I can run that `update:billing` manually but it suddenly stopped to run in schedule.

All of them were running till yesterday.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

`update:sales` also stopped now.

```js
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:sales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:branchsales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:sales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:branchsales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:branchsales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
Running scheduled command: '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' update:branchsales > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a answer to that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58021908/12755035). Hope it helps someone.

Just executed `php artisan cache:clear` on the project folder and all seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Check running processes, maybe the command is working (stuck) and do not run because of `withoutOverlapping`.

```sh
ps aux | grep 'php artisan'
```

Comment: Only update:branchsales running, any another guess?

Comment: I removed withoutOverlapping just for test, and it worked! I just dont know, why it was working yesterday, and today not, there was any update?

Comment: @ThRnk idk why but the problem in overlapping. Add logs for start/finish the console command. Or add some monitor package like a https://github.com/spatie/laravel-schedule-monitor

Answer (score 1):

I was having almost same issue few days back after some research I reached to the following solution,

```
    protected function osProcessIsRunning($needle)
        {
            // get process status. the "-ww"-option is important to get the full output!
            exec('ps aux -ww', $process_status);
    
            // search $needle in process status
            $result = array_filter($process_status, function($var) use ($needle) {
                return strpos($var, $needle);
            });
    
            // if the result is not empty, the needle exists in running processes
            if (!empty($result)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
     protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            if (!$this->osProcessIsRunning('update:sales')) {
                $schedule->command("update:branchsales")->everyFiveMinutes()->timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')->withoutOverlapping();
            }
//Similarly do for other two commands
    }
```

Now only run your schedule command in cron job like **schedule:run** it will also prevent extra load on the server, I have found this answer on Laracast forget link else I would have shared!

Comment: I removed withoutOverlapping just for test, and it worked! I just dont know, why it was working yesterday, and today not, there was any update?

Comment: As far as I know if we run manually command on our server it runs for some time and then after some interval, it stopped, so what I did was wrote this function and keep running schedule run after every minute so in case if it got stopped it restart our commands and after many approaches this was one which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with the incorrect project path specified in the crontab configuration.

To fix this,

1. Open the crontab configuration for editing:

   ```
    crontab -e
   ```
2. Add the following line to schedule Laravel tasks:

   ```
   * * * * * cd /path/to/project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
   ```